# Selecting data from a drop down list

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to get two values from a drop down list the **Subject Name** and the **ID**.
I have the **ID** set as selected value with the **Subject Name** being set as the data field.

Is there a way in which i can turn this data field into a text?

```
 string subjectName = ddlSubjectName.Text;
 string subjectId =Convert.ToString(ddlSubjectName.SelectedValue);
```

The Code above is putting the selectedvalue of the drop down to both the **subjectName** and the **subjectId** as I'm trying to add both these fields into a my sql database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can acces both items by

```
string subjectName = ddlSubjectName.SelectedItem.Text;
string subjectId = ddlSubjectName.SelectedItem.Value; // equals ddlSubjectName.SelectedValue
```

and they're both type `string`

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both the `Text` and `Value` properties of your [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) should contain the properties that you are looking for (i.e. the actual value and text associated to it) :

```
string subjectName = ddlSubjectName.SelectedItem.Text;
string subjectId = ddlSubjectName.SelectedItem.Value;
```